# Call a function at run time using shell scripting

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I've a requirement which is to call a function at run time with function name or by passing parameters using shell script.
My function is

```
PID=ps -ef | grep jmeter|grep -v grep
stop(){
echo "started killing the process\n"$PID""
kill $PID
}
```

I have other functions in the script to start the script etc. Now, I want to call the stop() function if only needed. So, I want to do it at run time.
Please tell me if anyone know this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This may be irrelevant but , your way of getting PID is wrong.

Comment: Can you please explain what do you mean by "call a function at run time"?

Comment: @soFan. i corrected the PID command, please check it once.

Comment: @Fazlin I have a script in which i am checking for a process PID's and also  a method to start the `jmeter` and run the `.jmx file`. I am able to call the start() and check_PID() methods by their names in the script. now, the user have to call the stop() function if necessary at run time (i.e) from the command line.

Comment: I advise to use `pkill` instead of parsing the `ps` command for a pid. `pgrep` might also be useful in that matter...

Comment: @soFan That is still a terrible way to get the pid, just use `pgrep`.

Comment: @soFan i want to run the stop() function through command line,if only user want to call it.

Comment: You shouldn't use the variable in the function — you should pass the PID to be killed as arguments to the function.  Global variables are bad; that global variable is bad.  The echo is a bit eccentric too.  Maybe `stop(){
echo "started killing the process(es) $*";
kill "$@";
}` would be more sensible. Then the user can run 'stop 31415 31232` or `stop -1 31415` or whatever they want. In fact, apart from the `echo`, it is equivalent to the `kill` command in terms of flexibility — so I'm not sure that it's a good idea.You need to decide how the user will decide whether they want to run `stop`.

Comment: Your machine very likely has a whole bunch of scripts the do very much the sort of thing you're looking for, and which you could use as examples.  Look in `/etc/init.d`.

Comment: Note also that you are still assigning `$PID`'s value incorrectly.  If you want the variable to take the output of a command as its value, then you need to use *command substitution*.  There are two syntaxes for that; one of them is `PID=$(ps -ef | grep jmeter | grep -v grep)`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler. Sorry,I'm new to shell scripting. can you be more elaborate.

Comment: @JohnBollinger. I changed the command. but i need to stop the service at run time.

Comment: @krishnapatamsetti, "i need to stop the service at run time": your point is what?

Comment: @JohnBollinger I have a script with methods to check the` PID's` and also to run the `.jmx` file. So, when I run this script from command line using `./script.sh` I get the PID's and the jmx file is executed. Now, while running this script in background, if the user wants to kill the execution he should be able to call the `stop()` function from the script. I don't understand how to do this

Comment: @krishnapatamsetti, perhaps I'm failing to understand something about your question, but as far as I can tell, what you describe is *exactly* what your system's init scripts (if indeed you have any) do.  In particular, these can be run interactively by a suitably-privileged user to manage (stop / start / etc.) system services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is I would do it: create script > create alias > call it at any time!

1. Create stp script

   ```
   #!/bin/sh

   read -p "Are you sure? Do you want to stop $1 process? y/n: " yn

   if [ ${yn} = "y" ]; then
     PID=`ps -ef|grep $1|grep -v 'grep'|awk '{print $2}'`

     echo "Killing Process=$1, ID=${PID} . . . "

     kill -9 ${PID}

   fi
   ```
2. Make `stp` alias so it can be use as command (Use fully qualified path to `stp` script)

   ```
   $ echo "alias stp=/home/user/stp" >> ~/.bash_profile
   $ source ~/.bash_profile
   $ sleep 4000 &
   [1] 11092
   ```
3. run `stp` command passing process name as argument as below
   Test:

   ```
   $ stp sleep
   Are you sure? Do you want to stop sleep process? y/n: y
   Killing Process=sleep, ID=11092 . . .
   [1]+  Killed                  sleep 4000
   Killed
   ```

Comment: I did the same thing yesterday. i got the result. Thank you

Comment: great... if this was the solution, please mark is as Answer - Thank you